# OpenCV Compare 2 Images and return result based on Ranking order

Tags: android, opencv

I am working on Image comparison using OpenCV, while comparing 2 image using histogram, getting the result in form of double value.

The question is, Is there any way to get the result in the form of Ranking order.
Kindly provide your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer the link for the above query

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 0):

you can use cv::sort() and cv::sortIdx() one comparison Mat in order to get sorted data and sorted data indices respectively.